# Relacionamento de Tabelas com CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Tenho duas tabelas: `artigos (id, categoria_id, titulo, texto, criacao)` e `categorias (id, nome)`. E elas possuem um relacionamento (`artigos.categoria_id => categorias.id`). E estou fazendo o CRUD, porém gostaria de saber como faço para criar um select que contém o nome das categorias, na parte de adicionar artigos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os seus relacionamentos estão todos funcionando corretamente, basta utilizar o [`FormHelper`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html), como é comum, informando o campo relacionado que ele já monta para você o `<select>` correspondente.

Por exemplo, no seu formulário para **Artigo**:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Artigo');
echo $this->Form->input('categoria_id');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Lembrando que o *value* de cada item é o **id** da categoria e o texto será o campo definido como [`displayField`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield) no seu *Model*.